# How to have an app send Push notifications?

Tags: foursquare

I'd like to create an application which sends you additional information about a venue when you checkin. My approach was going to be to add a comment to the checkin. The problem is the comment is added using the users oauth token therefore no "notification" is generated.

1. Is there someway to have an application send a user a notification as that "application"? (like in FB)
2. Is there some part of the API that I'm missing which would be a better match?
3. Is this something that would require the merchant api?

Answer (score 0):

Most applications that do something similar rely on SMS to notify the user. E.g. http://donteat.at/. Services like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) make the sending of text messages much easier for app developers.

Comment: Thanks akdotcom. I ended up creating a user account which then posts a comment.